# How to read multiple values in a list?

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I want a function that reads a list and finds a sequence of letters. If it finds them print something.

```
    lst = ['T','T','T','S','S','S','T','T']
    match = False
    strS = "S S S"
    
    for item in lst:
       if item in strS:
           match = True
    if match:
       print("Fail")
```

This does not work because there are a lot of lists with different combinations of T's and S's. I want it to only work when there are three S's in a row and this also reads any other S's and prints as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
big_str = ' '.join(lst)
found = strS in big_str
```

The first statement makes a single string form your list of letters, using space as the separator.  The second statement checks whether your search string is in the big string, and stores the result in `found`.  You can now either return or print `found`.